# how can i fit string in ml? because it say i cant convert string to float?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

i have a list . my_list is x=['Chevrolet Suburban',2020,40000] ,y=[5000]

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
x=['Chevrolet Suburban',2020,40000] 
y=[5000]
clf=clf.fit(x,y)
```

but it said that i can not convert string to float .
what do i do ?

Comment: You've asked a very complex question, you may want to read a bit about it. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-text-vectorization-2f2efbec6685) is an  article to get you started. if your "text" is just a list of cars then you can use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the value to a numeric value eg. maps all "Chevrolet Suburbans" to 1, all cars of another type to 2, and so on, in this way it shouldn't cause any problems